# How to Get an ID Attribute for a text-area that has been replaced by ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I am trying to validate using(JQuery) the text area that I have replaced with the ckeditor it seems like it can't pick up my text-area.

```
 here<div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("Instructions", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.TextArea("Instruction", new { @class = "form-control question-textarea", @style = "height:100px", @placeholder = "Enter instructions here" })
                            Instructions: <span id="linesUsed">0</span> of 15
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

My JavaScript and Jquery

```
enter code here <script>

    CKEDITOR.replace("Instruction");

</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var lines = 15;
        var linesUsed = $('#linesUsed');
        $('#cke_1_contents').keydown(function (e) {
            newLines = $(this).val().split("</p>").length;
            linesUsed.text(newLines);
            if (e.keyCode == 13 && newLines >= lines) {
                linesUsed.css('color', 'red');
                return false;
            }
            else {
                linesUsed.css('color', '');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

it seems my Jquery doesn't pick up the id for my text-area, has anyone have a clue on how will I get the text-area id in the ckeditor.

Comment: Could you add an ID to the container?  Then $('#newID .question-textarea')

Answer (score 0):

Try using event delegation you can read about it [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

"Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future."

change `$('#cke_1_contents').keydown(function (e) {`

to `$(document).on('keydown', '#cke_1_contents', function(e){} )`